# Cross-Entropy Loss for Prediction Distribution

Tags: loss-function, variance, cross-entropy, mean

I'm trying to adapt an example from the [Neural Tangents Cookbook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/neural-tangents/blob/main/notebooks/neural_tangents_cookbook.ipynb) which uses a variant of Mean Squared Error (MSE) loss suited for Regression prediction distributions given by Mean and Variance as opposed to direct logits:

$$loss_{MSE}=0.5\frac{\sum_i^S(y_i^2 + m_i^2 - 2m_iy_i + v_i)}{S}$$

This is for $S$ samples where $m_i$ and $v_i$ are the Mean and Variance of each sample's logits, respectively. This is a relatively simple function to understand and I can see how it's derived from MSE.

However, I can't figure out how to do the same thing for Cross-Entropy in order to do Classification instead of Regression. I also can't find any existing resources about such an adaptation. What would Cross-Entropy loss look like for a prediction distribution defined by Mean and Variance?